# Comparing git branches in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way to compare two git branches in Visual Studio 2017? I just want to see what files have been changed on my feature branch compared to the master branch.

I'm aware that I can go to Team Explorer > Branches > Right click and View History > and then double click a specific commit to see it's changes. However, I'm not aware of a way to the sum of changes for that branch.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Team Explorer > Branches > Right click your branch > View History > click the latest commit > ctrl + click the latest commit from master > right click > Compare Commits

edit: this only shows you the diff between commits. There's still no way that I'm aware of to compare branches via the VS interface.

However, if you want to see all the changes you made in a feature branch before submitting a PR, using command line you can do this:

`checkout master`

`merge <branch-name> --no-commit --no-ff`

and then look at Changes in Team Explorer to see all the changes you made in a branch before submitting a PR.

Comment: This doesn't work. Use the Github extension for Visual Studio instead. You can just review pull requests with that, which is all I needed this for anyway

Comment: This does work. It's just using git's [diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command. I wish you could edit the current branch as you compare (since people may be actively commenting in person), but this at least compares them through the UI

Comment: I should have said this only works for comparing commits. Not branches (with multiple commits). Since posting this I found out a way to compare branches without submiting a PR, though (see edit above)